# Auto copy to the clipboard when a button is clicked in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an application in Rails 3 where I have a text field which  contains a URL:

```
 <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<%= linkbunch_url(@link.link) %>" class="span4" id="url_copy" />
```

Next to this I have a button:

```
<button type="button" id="copy_link" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-share" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Copy To ClipBoard</button>
```

When someone clicks on this button, I want the url in the text field to be copied into the clipboard. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that with Ruby through the web browser.

You need a JavaScript method instead. Look at "[How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)".

Comment: I'm following the method mentioned https://github.com/HaNdTriX/zclip-rails and also from http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that worked for me. I used this [gemfile](https://github.com/sadiqmmm/clipboard-rails)

and only installed these gems:

```
gem 'clipboard-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

also, include these in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
//= require clipboard
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```